# How do I convert an API resource class in Laravel 5.5 to an array BEFORE returning from controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Ordinarily, in Laravel 5.5, when using an api resource class, you simply return the resource class instance from your controller method, like so:

```
public function show(Request $request, MyModel $model)
{
    return new MyModelResource($model);
}
```

This converts the model to an array (and ultimately to json) in the response to the client.

However... I am trying to figure out how to convert everything to an array BEFORE returning it from the controller method. I tried this:

```
public function show(Request $request, MyModel $model)
{
    $array = (new MyModelResource($model))->toArray($request);

    // ...
}
```

The problem here is that any relationships loaded on the resource aren't also converted to an array. They show up inside `$array` as an instance of a resource class. Obviously calling `toArray()` manually does not result in a recursive call, and methods such as `->whenLoaded('relationship_name')` aren't really respected either.

So how do I get Laravel to do everything it does to convert the resource to an array recursively WITHOUT having to return it from my controller method?

Comment: Have you tried calling `->resolve($request)` instead of toArray()?  Examine the base Resource class for more info.

Comment: @Devon Just tried it, and the array returned still has object instances in the relationships.

Comment: @Devon However, I was able to accomplish what I ultimately needed to do with this (too complicated to explain here), so thanks!

Comment: @fronzee that comment is equivalent to "Don't worry, figured it out"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the `resolve` method on the resource class. See [definition](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/JsonResource.php#L83).

From the looks of it, it should handle converting the relationships into an array as well. Just be sure you are [setting up your resource relationships properly](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources#writing-resources).

Answer (score 2):

Neither the `toArray()` or `resolve()` methods convert the related models to arrays which is really annoying because you'd expect them to.

You're better off using `toResponse(null)` which will return a `JsonRepsonse` object. Which you can then use the `getContent()` method for a json encoded string or the `getData()` method for an object.

So if you wanted an array **not wrapped in a data variable** it would be:

```
$array = json_decode(
    json_encode(
        (new MyModelResource($model))
            ->toResponse(null)
            ->getData()
            ->data
    ), 
true);
```

Ugly but it works unlike the accepted answer.